# how to create a barplot in NetLogo where bars are side by side

Tags: netlogo

I have two lists that I want to plot as sided bars:

```
[44.44 28.57 50 22.72 37.52]
[64.10 75 76.19 55.55 72.22]
```

I'd like to have a result as in the figure below, but I don't understand how to achieve this in netlogo, given the available primitives for plotting: "histogram" is definitely not useful here, while "plot" requires data to be a single value not a list.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really not a trivial task. First of all, you won`t get the x labels on the x-axis right, because NetLogo plots cannot handle categorical axes scales (the gap between groups cannot skipped). However, it is possible to create filled bar charts with NetLogo. I wrote a procedure some time ago and adapted it to your needs:

```
to go

  ca
  ;; Define plot variables:
  let y.a [44.44 28.57 50 22.72 37.52]
  let y.b [64.10 75 76.19 55.55 72.22]
  let plotname "plot 1"
  let ydata (list y.a y.b)
  let pencols (list 16 56)
  let barwidth 2
  let step 0.01
  ;; Call the plotting procedure
  groupedbarplot plotname ydata pencols barwidth step

end

to groupedbarplot [plotname ydata pencols barwidth step]

  ;; Get n from ydata -> number of groups (colors)
  let n length ydata
  let i 0
  ;; Loop over ydata groups (colors)
  while [i < n]
  [
    ;; Select the current ydata list and compute x-values depending on number of groups (n), current group (i) and bardwith
    let y item i ydata
    let x n-values (length y) [? -> (i * barwidth) + (? * (((n + 1) * barwidth)))]
    print y
    print x

    ;; Initialize the plot (create a pen, set the color, set to bar mode and set plot-pen interval)
    set-current-plot plotname
    create-temporary-plot-pen (word i)
    set-plot-pen-color item i pencols
    set-plot-pen-mode 1
    set-plot-pen-interval step

    ;; Loop over xy values from the two lists:
    let j 0
    while [j < length x]
    [
      ;; Select current item from x and y and set x.max for current bar, depending on barwidth
      let x.temp item j x
      let x.max x.temp + (barwidth * 0.97)
      let y.temp item j y

      ;; Loop over x-> xmax and plot repeatedly with increasing x.temp to create a filled barplot
      while [x.temp < x.max]
      [
        plotxy x.temp y.temp
        set x.temp (x.temp + step)
      ] ;; End of x->xmax loop
      set j (j + 1)
    ] ;; End of dataloop for current group (i)
    set i (i + 1)
  ] ;; End of loop over all groups

end
```

You may have to adjust the plotname within the `go`procedure and then execute the `go` procedure to perform the plotting. One advantage of this method is, that it is quite flexible regarding the number of groups you want to plot next to each other. You just have to submit a list of y coordinates (one list for each group nested in one big list) and a corresponding list of pencolors for each group. You can just add more y lists and colors to plot more groups. The groupedbarplot procedure loops trough these groups and calculates matching x-coordinates (based on the number of groups and the barwidth). The plotting itself is nested inside another loop to plot the y coordinates repeatedly with increasing x coordinates (increment step). This creates many small bars next to each other in order to create the illusion of a filled barplot.